# Accessing Package Private element between parent / child classloaders

Tags: java, classloader

In a Java application, I have two classes declared, one class (`One`) declared in ClassLoader A and another class (`Two`) declared in ClassLoader B.  ClassLoader A is B's parent.  Both of these classes have the same package (ie: `org.test`).

I cannot seem to access `One`'s package private methods or varialbes from `Two` event though A is B'd parent ClassLoader, I get an `IllegalAccessError` exception.  I understand that package private accessibility is based both on the package name and the ClassLoader.

Is there a way to re-associate `One` and `Two` so that `Two` can access `One`'s Package Private elements?

Here's the test to demonstrate this:

```
package org.test;

public class ClassLoaderTest {

    @Test
    public void testLoading() throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
        One one = new One();
        one.value = "test";

        MemoryClassLoader classLoader = new MemoryClassLoader();

        String name = one.getClass().getPackage().getName() + ".Two";

        classLoader.add(name,
            "package org.test;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "public class Two{\n" +
            "    public static String getValue(One one){\n" +
            "        return one.value;\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}");

        Class<?> twoClass = classLoader.loadClass(name);

        assertEquals("test", twoClass.getMethod("getValue", One.class).invoke(null, one));
    }
}

public class One{
    String value;
}
```

MemoryClassLoader can be found [here](https://github.com/johncarl81/transfuse/blob/master/transfuse/src/test/java/org/androidtransfuse/gen/classloader/MemoryClassLoader.java).

which errors with:

```
testLoading(org.test.ClassLoaderTest)  Time elapsed: 0.214 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.test.ClassLoaderTest.testLoading(ClassLoaderTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.test.One.value from class org.test.Two
    at org.test.Two.getValue(Two.java:5)
    ... 34 more
```

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I've produced a Gist with a self contained test demonstrating this [here](https://gist.github.com/johncarl81/9230572).

Comment: Please post your stack trace.

Comment: AFAIK, a package is actually a combination of the class loader and the package name.  OSGi for example doesn't allow a package to be used from multiple modules (and each one has it's own classloader)

Comment: @chrylis Added stack trace and example

Comment: @PeterLawrey Right, I am aware of this.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: @johncarl Why do you need some special way around? As you correctly said, your classes are effectively in *different* packages. Do what you would usually do in such a situation. Make the field public, or provide public property access methods.

Comment: @PavelS its a long story, my requirement is to access package private and protected fields, methods and constructors between classloaders.

Comment: @johncarl What if you then provide some hidden reflection-based access mechanism that would make the package-level field accessible programmatically, provided the `SecurityManager` allows for that.

Comment: @PavelS I'm attempting to do this without reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to re-associate One and Two so that Two can access
>   One's Package Private elements?

**Simple Answer:** With Reflection: **YES**; Without Reflection: **NO**.

**Detailed Answer:** Java has its own mechanisms to control the access, prevention of users of a package or class from depending on unnecessary details of the implementation of that package or class. If access is permitted, then the accessed entity is said to be accessible. **Accessibility is a static property** that can be determined at compile time; it depends only on types and declaration modifiers.

From [Java SE specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1)

> If the member or constructor is declared private, then access is
>   permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level
>   class that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor. A
>   private class member or constructor is accessible only within the body
>   of the top level class that encloses the declaration of the member or
>   constructor. It is not inherited by subclasses.

Hence, it is not possible in Java SE **without** using Reflection API.

If Reflection API is used, then the static introspection of accessibility is changed to **dynamic**. Classes are loaded dynamically, binding is done dynamically, and object instances are created dynamically on the fly when they are needed. What has not been very dynamic historically is the ability to manipulate "anonymous" classes. In this context, an anonymous class is one that is loaded or presented to a Java class at run time and whose type was previously unknown to the Java program.

Snippet of class & method access code using Reflection API

```
Object o = hi.getClass().getMethod("foo").invoke(hi); 
Method m = o.getClass().getMethod("bar"); 
m.setAccessible(true); 
m.invoke(o);
```

Take an in-depth look at the [Java Reflection API](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077015/java-se/take-an-in-depth-look-at-the-java-reflection-api.html).

*It is not always necessary to prove that impossible itself says I M Possible. In this case Reflection API has reinvented the wheel for us, we shouldn't be looking to reinvent it all together again from scratch.*  (on a lighter note, nothing to offense.)

Shishir

Comment: Thanks Shishir, I am well aware of the reflection API and the technique to change modifier accessibility.  The end result of this effort is to test that a package-private specific architecture (ie: package-private and protected both work, but private does not) so I think changing the accessibility limits and possibly breaks this test.  That being said, there may not be a better way (other than the compile-into technique I mentioned below).

Answer (score 3):

This is expected, since the definition for the qualification of any element in Java starts with its classloader and then their package. That said, it won't give you any errors at compile time, but as the runtime package is different, will result in an access violation and thus, generate an exception.

This article may help you to put some more light on this matter: http://www.cooljeff.co.uk/2009/05/03/the-subtleties-of-overriding-package-private-methods/

Although, you'll still be able to acces these methods by reflection, calling `Method.setAccessible(boolean)` before the method invocation.

Comment: An answer I am hoping for is something around re-associating / moving / reloading the given class to a classloader and avoiding needing relection.

Comment: And I want a machine that turns all the sadness in the world into bacon, but that's, my friend, is somehow impossible.

Comment: Hah. Looking at this project I suspect it may be possible: https://code.google.com/p/transloader/

Answer (score 0):

One soultion is to compile the class `One` into the classloader:

```
public class ClassLoaderTest {

    @Test
    public void testLoading() throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchFieldException {
        String packageName = "org.test";

        MemoryClassLoader classLoader = new MemoryClassLoader();

        Map<String, String> toCompile = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String oneName = packageName + ".One";
        toCompile.put(oneName,
                "package org.test;\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "public class One{\n" +
                        "        String value;\n" +
                        "    }");

        String twoName = packageName + ".Two";
        toCompile.put(twoName,
                "package org.test;\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "public class Two{\n" +
                        "    public static String getValue(One one){\n" +
                        "        return one.value;\n" +
                        "    }\n" +
                        "}");

        classLoader.add(toCompile);

        Class<?> oneClass = classLoader.loadClass(oneName);
        Object one = oneClass.newInstance();

        Field valueField = oneClass.getDeclaredField("value");
        valueField.setAccessible(true);
        valueField.set(one, "test");
        valueField.setAccessible(false);

        Class<?> twoClass = classLoader.loadClass(twoName);

        assertEquals("test", twoClass.getMethod("getValue", oneClass).invoke(null, one));
    }
}
```

Not the best solution as you have to treat your java source as Strings.

Answer (score 0):

> ... I'm attempting to do this without reflection. – johncarl ...

Just an wild idea and it's certainly a *very wrong* thing to do (from a Java perspective), but:

You could load a library file (***.dll, *.so**, etc.) into your Java process (via JNI). Then you could access the full Java process space from the C/C++ side and call any existing method.

Comment: Certainly a wild approach.